# In PDF file generated by Apache PdfBox, can generation of /ID in trailer be turned off?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox to go and generate accessible PDF files, and I also need to make unit tests for them. I've seen some testing solutions where the strategy is to convert each page of the PDF into an image, and compared pixel by pixel the test PDF and the expected PDF. This by itself is not enough however: there's an accessibility xml tree intended to allow blind people to have the PDF be read out loud to them in the metadata. That wouldn't be tested with such an approach.

In the output PDF file, the only line that's different each time I generate the same PDF is the `/ID` which is optional. `/ID` can be useful if the PDF were to be modified, but the PDF I'm generating is read only with no forms to modify data. It can also be useful for encryption, but this is an unencrypted document. I can think of nothing to be gained by having it in my use case. It only gets in the way of my unit testing as I can't just directly compare 2 pdfs files and make sure they match exactly.

I mean I suppose if there really is no way of getting rid of the trailer `/ID`, I could read in the PDFs as text documents and make sure every line matches except for the `/ID` lines in the trailers.

[image: pdf different /id in trailers]

Edit: sorry, forgot to mention that I wanted to see if this was possible using the Java API. I forgot that Apache PDFBox also has a command line interface.

Comment: I looked into the source code, PDFBox always sets the ID.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I see, thank you. I'll just go ahead and write some code to parse the PDF file and ignore the ID line rather than the lazy approach of making sure the PDF files match byte for byte entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You can postprocess with:

`cpdf -remove-id in.pdf -o out.pdf`

This involves reading and writing the PDF, so it may alter the PDF files, for example it may renumber objects - so you would want to retain the inputs. But for the false-positive-removal part of the problem, it should do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do this in java. Basically I'm sending a PDF in the response body of a REST request, and this PDF does not exist as a file in the file system.  Would you happen to know how to do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

XY problem

Your stated reason for alter ID is to ensure two identical files except for that entry are the same. However having just one ignorable field is not a problem for testing equality.

say the FC result is something like

```
***** InverseField2a.pdf
trailer
<</Size 17/Info 1 0 R/Root 2 0 R/ID[<582DE60B279DBF07B6232BDD8F8A798F><5031F1B55BEB389B6DB47E7066E40862>]>>
startxref
13024
%%EOF
***** INVERSEFIELD2B.PDF
trailer
<</Size 17/Info 1 0 R/Root 2 0 R/ID[<582DE60B279DBF07B6232BDD8F8A798F><E77CE07862E6178EE45F4D934D3FC7B5>]>>
startxref
12251
%%EOF
*****
```

we can ignore the ID difference it is the more important difference in startxref that is critical as the files differ in size thus ID is irrelevant the size changed so the ID changed, but could just as easily be equal IDS .

If the size does not change and only the ~ID changes that's just as easy to ignore, as there is no other change including size difference to be shown.

```
***** InverseField2a.pdf
trailer
<</Size 17/Info 1 0 R/Root 2 0 R/ID[<582DE60B279DBF07B6232BDD8F8A798F><5031F1B55BEB389B6DB47E7066E40862>]>>
startxref
***** INVERSEFIELD2B.PDF
trailer
<</Size 17/Info 1 0 R/Root 2 0 R/ID[<582DE60B279DBF07B6232BDD8F8A798F><E77CE07862E6178EE45F4D934D3FC7B5>]>>
startxref
*****
```